# How can I change font in Latex?

Tags: fontsize

I would like to change the font size in LaTeX from 12 to 14 how can I do that?

I am using the following code but it's not working:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12bp]{article}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can use the `extsizes` package and write as the first line: `\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}`.